# StartService returns null Android Service

Tags: android, service, android-broadcast, countdowntimer

I need to start a countdowntimer in backgroud service and show it on My fragment. This is where I am currently.

ComponentName c  is null after calling startService.
I am not sure how I can debug this using debugger.

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map, container, false);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        controlv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.controls_parked);
        parker_info = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.parked_info);
        take_to_car_btn= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.walk_to_Car);
        unPark = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.un_park);
        timer = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer_btn);
        myContext = getActivity();
        mDpi = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;


        timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ComponentName c = getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), TimerService.class));
                Log.i(TAG, "Started service");


            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent){
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Timer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is my Service :

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "TimerService";
    public static final String TIMER_BR = "parking.group6.csc413.projectmap_timer";
    Intent timer_intent = new Intent(TIMER_BR);
    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timer_intent.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(timer_intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };

        cdt.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And yes my manifest file has:

```
<service android:name=".TimerService"/>
```

Comment: Are you certain that `TimerService` is under the root of your package and not under a subpackage or otherwise different package?

Answer (score 0):

ComponentName is not null only if the Service was already started or is already running. If the service doesn't exist yet, null is return. To start your CountDownTimer, you can use an action:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TimerService.class);
intent.setAction("START");
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

when `onStartCommand` is invoked, check if the action is equals to `START`. If it is, start your `CountDownTimer`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if ("START".equals(intent.getAction()) {
        // start CountDownTimer
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: i tried that i put a breakpoint at startService and one at onStartCommand, onStartCommand breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: In my experience, the result of `startService()` is non-`null` regardless of whether the service was already running, so long as it's declared in the manifest.

Comment: @sam good for you. Unfortunately the documentation states something else

Comment: Just looked it up again and it says:

Comment: ` If the service is being started or is already running, the ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else if the service does not exist null is returned.`